# How to find n consecutive numbers in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have numbers starting from 1 to 50 and then 90 to 200 in my database and I want to fetch 100 consecutive numbers then the result should be 90 to 189.
Records in my table are more than 10 million.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute `$n` with the desired number:

```
SELECT c1.id 
FROM consecutive c1 
WHERE $n = (SELECT count(*) 
           FROM consecutive c2 
           WHERE c2.id 
           BETWEEN c1.id AND (c1.id + $n - 1)
           );
```

This does a full table scan for each number, combined with a range scan. It finds all possible combinations (returning the first figure in the chain, so add a LIMIT 1 for better performance if you just want to find the first result. Example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE consecutive (id int PRIMARY KEY);
mysql> INSERT INTO consecutive VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11);
mysql> SELECT c1.id FROM consecutive c1 WHERE 5 = 
       (SELECT count(*) FROM consecutive c2 
        WHERE c2.id BETWEEN c1.id AND (c1.id + 4)
       ) LIMIT 1;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  6 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It could probably be optimized to be done in a simple table scan with the help of variables, but this uses simpler and more standard syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.Its working perfectly fine on smaller set of data but in my case data set is quite large and it takes around 10 seconds which will not fulfill my need.I have done indexing on my table.But is there any better way to fine tune it? Sorry for this silly question but I am not very good at MySql.Thanks